# nodeJS: how to call an async function within a loop in another async function call

Tags: node.js, async-await, request-promise

I am trying to call one async function from inside a loop run by another async function. These functions call APIs and I am using `request-promise` using `nodeJS`.

**functions.js file**

```
const rp = require("request-promise");


// function (1)
async email_views: emailId => {
    let data = {};
    await rp({
       url: 'myapiurl',
       qs: { accessToken: 'xyz', emailID: emailId },
       method: 'GET'
    })
      .then( body => { data = JSON.parse(body) })
      .catch( error => { console.log(error} );

    return data;
};
```

The above JSON looks like this:

```
...
data:{
   records: [
      {
        ...
        contactID: 123456,
        ...
      },
      {
        ...
        contactID: 456789,
        ...
      }
   ]
}
...
```

I am running a loop to get individual record, where I am getting a `contactID` associated with each of them.

```
// function#2 (also in functions.js file)
async contact_detail: contactId => {
    let data = {};
    await rp({
       url: 'myapiurl2',
       qs: { accessToken: 'xyz', contactID: contactId },
       method: 'GET'
    })
      .then( body => { data = JSON.parse(body) })
      .catch( error => { console.log(error} );

    return data;

};
```

The above function takes one `contactId` as parameter and gets that contact's detail calling another API endpoint.

Both functions work fine when they are called separately. But I am trying to do it inside a loop like this:

```
...
const result = await email_views(99999); // function#1
const records = result.data.records;
...
let names = "";
for( let i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
    ...
    const cId = records[i].contactID;
    const contact = await contact_detail(cId); // function#2
    names += contact.data.firstName + " " + contact.data.lastName + " ";
    ...
}
console.log(names);
...
```

The problem is I am only getting the first **contact** back from the above code block, i.e. even I have 20 records from `function#1`, in the loop when I am calling `contact_detail` (function#2) for each `contactID (cId)`, I get contact detail once, i.e. for the first `cId` only. For rest I get nothing!

What is the correct way to achieve this using `nodeJs`?

**UPDATE:**

```
const { App } = require("jovo-framework");
const { Alexa } = require("jovo-platform-alexa");
const { GoogleAssistant } = require("jovo-platform-googleassistant");
const { JovoDebugger } = require("jovo-plugin-debugger");
const { FileDb } = require("jovo-db-filedb");

const custom = require("./functions");
const menuop = require("./menu");
const stateus = require("./stateus");
const alexaSpeeches = require("./default_speech");
const app = new App();

app.use(new Alexa(), new GoogleAssistant(), new JovoDebugger(), new FileDb());

let sp = "";
async EmailViewsByContactIntent() {
    try {
      const viewEmailId =
        this.$session.$data.viewEmailIdSessionKey != null
          ? this.$session.$data.viewEmailIdSessionKey
          : this.$inputs.view_email_Id_Number.value;
      let pageIndex =
        this.$session.$data.viewEmailPageIndex != null
          ? this.$session.$data.viewEmailPageIndex
          : 1;

      const result = await custom.email_views_by_emailId(
        viewEmailId,
        pageIndex
      );
      const records = result.data.records;
      if (records.length > 0) {
        const totalRecords = result.data.paging.totalRecords;
        this.$session.$data.viewEmailTotalPages = totalRecords;
        sp = `i have found a total of ${totalRecords} following view records. `;
        if (totalRecords > 5) {
          sp += `i will tell you 5 records at a time. for next 5 records, please say, next. `;

          this.$session.$data.viewEmailIdSessionKey = this.$inputs.view_email_Id_Number.value;
          this.$session.$data.viewEmailPageIndex++;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
          const r = records[i];

          /* Here I want to pass r.contactID as contactId in the function contact_detail like this: */

          const contact = await custom.contact_detail(r.contactID);
          const contact_name = contact.data.firstName + " " + contact.data.lastName;

         /* The above two lines of code fetch contact_name for the first r.contactID and for the rest I get an empty string only. */

          const formatted_date = r.date.split(" ")[0];
          sp += `contact ID ${spellOut_speech_builder(
            r.contactID
          )} had viewed on ${formatted_date} from IP address ${
            r.ipAddress
          }. name of contact is, ${contact_name}. `;
        }
        if (totalRecords > 5) {
          sp += ` please say, next, for next 5 records. `;
        }
      } else {
        sp = ``;
      }
      this.ask(sp);
    } catch (e) {
      this.tell(e);
    }
  }
```

I am building an alexa skill using `JOVO` framework and `nodeJS`.

**UPDATE #2**
As a test, I only returned the `contactId` which I am passing to the contact_detail function and I am getting the correct value back to the above code under my first **UPDATE**.

```
async contact_detail: contactId => {
   return contactId;
}
```

It seems even after getting the value right, the function is somehow failing to execute. However, the same `contact_detail` function works perfectly OK, when I am calling it from another place. Only doesn't not work inside a loop.

What could be the reason?
I must be missing something but don't know what!

Comment: I'm not sure about the way data is returned. I could be wrong and it's perfectly legit. I just get nervous seeing logic split between the done function and elsewhere (i.e. the return statement). I would favour awaiting the data inside a try catch block, or potentially just returning the promise and doing a Promise.all() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Your `contact_detail()` function call doesn't show any code that is actually using the argument you pass to it.  If it wasn't using the `contact_id` passed in, then it would always give you the same result, no matter what you passed it.  Other than that, we need to see the rest of the code in your `for` loop to see where things are going wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am not sure what exactly you require. I have updated code blocks and the loop section according to my understanding from what you said. Please let me know if that helps. Thank you!

Comment: Any chance that `contactID` and `contactId` are mixed up somewhere?  What is supposed to be in the querystring?  I'm just trying to see why `contact_detail(cId);` would always get you the first contact every time.  It seems like something is wrong with your query.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is not getting the first contact every time. What I am getting is the name of the contact say Andrew for the first time, and then for rest of the records (`contactID`s) I am getting empty value.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated the post with complete code.

Comment: Where is `sp` defined?

Comment: `sp` is defined globally as `let sp = ''` and then updated inside every function as per requirement.

Comment: Is this server code?  If so, `sp` can easily be getting trounced by other requests that get to run during your asynchronous operations.  I don't know why you would define that globally.  Your use of it seems entirely self contained inside of `EmailViewsByContactIntent()`.  It should be a local variable in that function.

Comment: It called server side APIs defined in an external javascript file. I have updated the question again. Please check. I understand what you are saying. But `sp` is working perfectly OK. I also tried by defining a variable in local scope. But the `contact_name` is issue still persists. `sp` is defined only in `app.js` file and it is not being used anywhere else other than `app.js`.

Comment: Well, `sp` has a concurrency problem that's a ticking time bomb and it will bite you when your server is under multi-user load.  `sp` should be a local variable in this function.  Probably not the source of the problem in this question, but a BUG none-the-less that you should fix.

Comment: Did you `console.log(result.data.records)` and see if all the data is there?

Comment: What version of node.js are you running?

Comment: @jfriend00 I will make `sp` local for sure. I understand the potential issue with multi-user. Let me try the other suggestion of logging.

Comment: node version is 10.14.0

Comment: If `contact_detail()` encounters an error, it will resolve with an empty object because you aren't actually propagating errors (your `.catch()` is eating errors).  Since it sounds like you may be getting an empty object back, this sound like a suspect.  That function is written horribly too.  You should just `return rp().then()` and you should either remove the `.catch()` or rethrow the error inside of it so that errors propagate.  That function has no need to `async` either since you can just return the promise directly from `rp()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 may I please request you to tell me exactly how to write this contact_detail part? I am sure, you have already understood that I am very new to this platform.

Comment: I posted an answer that shows a rewritten `contact_detail()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing async await and promises together which is causing you confusion. You typically would use one of the other(as async await effectivly provides syntax sugar so you can avoid dealing with the verbose promise code) in a given location.

Because you mixed the two you are in a weird area where the behavior is harder to nail down.

If you want to use async await your functions should look like

```
async contact_detail: contactId => {
  try {
    const body = await rp({
       url: 'myapiurl2',
       qs: { ... }
    });

    return JSON.parse(body);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    //This will return undefined in exception cases. You may want to catch at a higher level.
  }
};
```

or with promises

```
async contact_detail: contactId => {
    return rp({
       url: 'myapiurl2',
       qs: { ... }
    })
      .then( body => JSON.parse(body))
      .catch( error => { 
         console.log(error);
         //This will return undefined in exception cases. You probably dont want to catch here.
      });
};
```

Keep in mind your current code executing the function will do each call in series. If you want to do them in parallel you will need to call the function a bit differently and use something like Promise.all to resolve the result.

Comment: This is a good style recommendation, but I don't think it actually fixed anything.

Comment: This is not merely a style recommendation. Modifying a variable defined outside an async scope is always trouble.  It is often the case that cleaning this up resolves issues.

Comment: In this particular case, there's nothing wrong with using a `for` loop to collect data into a variable defined before the `for` loop.   That's been done for ages.  No problem with that.  Even with an `await`.  Still no problem.  You haven't explained what actual problem you've fixed for them.  I agree there are better styles to use than that, but I don't see what problem you've fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
...
const result = await email_views(99999); // function#1
const records = result.data.records;
...
let names = "";
await Promise.all(records.map(async record => {
    let cId = record.contactID;
    let contact = await contact_detail(cId);
    names += contact.data.firstName + " " + contact.data.lastName + " ";
});
console.log(names);
...
```

Comment: Its bad practice to modify a variable defined outside an async scope. In this case the concatenation order will vary based on the time each request takes in contact_detail.  A better implementation would return contact.data.firstName + " " + contact.data.lastName + " "; and perform a join on the resolution of Promise.all

Comment: This puts the contacts in no defined order (basically random).  I'm also not sure what problem it solves.  The issue appears to be that `contact_detail(cId);` only returns the first contact info everytime.

Comment: It is not working. Getting reference error `.length` is not defined. The objective is to get the `contactID` from each record in `records` and then pass the same in another async function as `contactId` to get the detail of that contact. For the first call I am getting the correct contact name back, but for rest `contactID`s, I am getting an empty (`''`) string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer only because I need to show you some multi-line code as part of throubleshooting this.  Not sure this solves your issue yet, but it is a problem.

Your `contact_detail()` function is not properly returning errors.  Instead, it eats the error and resolves with an empty object.  That could be what is causing  your blank names.  It should just return the promise directly and if you want to log the error, then it needs to rethrow.  Also, there's no reason for it to be declared `async` or to use `await`.  You can just return the promise directly.  You can also let request-promise parts the JSON response for you too.

Also, I notice, there appears to be a syntax error in your `.catch()` which could also be part of the problem.

```
contact_detail: contactId => {
    return rp({
       url: 'myapiurl2',
       qs: { accessToken: 'xyz', contactID: contactId },
       json: true,
       method: 'GET'
    }).catch( error => { 
        // log error and rethrow so any error propagates
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    });
};
```

Then, you would call this like you originally were (note you still use `await` when calling it because it returns a promise):

```
...
const result = await email_views(99999); // function#1
const records = result.data.records;
...
let names = "";
for( let i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
    ...
    const cId = records[i].contactID;
    const contact = await contact_detail(cId);
    names += contact.data.firstName + " " + contact.data.lastName + " ";
    ...
}
console.log(names);
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Here is what I get for each call of `contact_detail` inside the loop:

`i have found a total of 230 following view records. i will tell you 5 records at a time. for next 5 records, please say, next. {"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false} please say, next, for next 5 records.`

Comment: @SubrataSarkar - Are you still doing `const contact = await contact_detail(cId)` inside your loop?  It doesn't look like you are.  Those look like pending promises.

Comment: I have taken out the `await` since the main function that you suggested is not an `async` one any more. so now it reads `let contact = custom.contact_detail(r.contactID);`

Comment: @SubrataSarkar - Put the await back.  Your function returns a promise.  You need await or .then() to get the value from the promise.

Comment: @SubrataSarkar - I added more to my answer about how you call it with `await`.

Comment: I am taking this very approach from the beginning and getting the name back for the first call and then for all subsequent calls I am getting an empty string. That was the original issue.

Comment: I am sorry for troubling you for such a long time! I will try again and only come back to you if I still cannot get it working even after implementing your suggested way.